# Is there a command line tool to tell me which JAR a particular Class is in

Tags: java

Is there a command line tool that will crack open a JAR file and locate a particular .class file in it?  Something that would let me walk a directory tree in search of which Jar(s) have a particular class like...

```
find . -name *jar -exec jaregrep -l "org.bob.PriceListViewUpdate" {} \;
REST/prices.jar
v2/REST/prices.jar
```

Something like this must exist.  Where do I get it?

Comment: This does not directly answer your question. Sorry. Directly, I don't know how to do that. But, you might take a look at Apache Maven. Their repo structure might be appealing to you for this very reason. Cheers!

Comment: @CodyS thanks for the thought, but the problem isn't a dependency one, its a "this class is somewhere in the 297 JARS, but which one" in a legacy codebase.

Comment: Look at Jarscan and what it claims it can do http://www.inetfeedback.com/jarscan/

Comment: Jarscan has promise, but @Dev's answer solved the problem at hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know what directory the jar is you can use `grep` in linux. Run this command from a directory above the suspect jar files. It will tell you which jar file (or files) has it. I do this all the time when I'm looking for something in the mess of jars JBoss uses.

```
grep -rail --include=*.jar org.bob.PriceListViewUpdate
```

Answer (score 1):

[JWhich](http://www.fullspan.com/proj/jwhich/index.html) provides command-line tools to find the jar file which contains the resource you are searching for.

Answer (score 1):

I use this one:

```
#!/bin/sh

find $1 -name *jar | while read JARFILE
do
    COUNT=$(unzip -qq -l "$JARFILE" "$2" | wc -l)
    if [ $COUNT -gt 0 ] ; then
            echo "$JARFILE: $COUNT matches"
    fi
done
```

ie:

```
./findclass.sh  workspace-indigo/ org/objectweb/*
```

You can use globs for package names, but you have to specify package names with slashes instead of fullstops as a backdraw.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add TattleTale to this list. It's a tool to generate an detailed HTML report of a list of jars.

Useful usually to debug version conflicts.

http://www.jboss.org/tattletale