# 'which' command equivalent for finding resource(s) on Java classpath

Tags: java, classpath, utility

Is there an equivalent of the UNIX 'which' command, i.e. for given resource(s), traverse all classpath components and tell me in which component(s) it is found? **In particular when there are multiple occurrences on the classpath?**

(Context: I just spent the best part of a day chasing a bug which boiled down to a very long classpath having a source directory with stale source preceding (and thus eclipsing) a compiled jar with compiled newer code.)

(Yes I know you can get this with *'java -verbose'* but that produces tons of output.

Maybe ***'java -verbose ... | grep SpecificResource'*** is the best way?)

Comment: Similar to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/9105646/260633

Comment: Thanks. I searched but did not find that, his question is more restrictive. The .class need not necessarily be inside a .jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a shell script for finding classes within a set of JARs. The relevant part is this:

```
find /my/jars -name \*.jar | while read jar; do
    jar -tf "$jar" | fgrep --label="$jar" -l foo/bar/SomeClass.class
done
```

which lists all JARs in `/my/jars` containing a file `foo/bar/SomeClass.class`.

**Edit**

This one-liner from the comments also works:

```
grep -rail --include=\*.jar foo/bar/SomeClass.class /my/jars
```

Comment: unzip -l your_library.jar | grep ClassName :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing that for a whole set of JARs.

Comment: `grep -rail --include=*.jar <classname>` from the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9105776/260633.

Comment: I didn't realise that `grep` worked with binary files! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See [jwhich](http://www.fullspan.com/proj/jwhich/index.html), I believe it does exactly what you are looking for. It is not difficult to roll your own but why do that when it is readily available?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to take your classpath and search each element for the class(es) in question.

In theory, classes are guaranteed to be loaded in classpath order. If your classpath has a wildcard element, however, it's no longer deterministic. So you'd need to check for those and just dump out the classpath elements that match the resource in question.

A short JRuby/Groovy script should do it if `java -verbose` doesn't give you all the info you need.

Comment: Right, Wildcards on classpaths Considered Harmful. Always blast them into a static list of subdirectories/jars, to avoid future surprises.

Comment: @smci No, I wouldn't generalize it like that at all. Normally you don't have a source directory on your classpath, and your dependencies are normalized. Wildcards are a great shortcut for distributions. Of course, these days most dependencies aren't managed manually anyway, but wildcards themselves aren't fundamentally bad.

Comment: if you have multiple classpath components (and especially if they have subdirectories), wildcards are a nightmare. You want each resource to be found precisely where it is supposed to be, or else fail.

Comment: @smci That's a lot of ifs, and you're assuming there are multiple dependency satisfiers. Obviously if you've got pathological library collections, wildcards aren't a great idea. OTOH, if you're in that situation, things have already gone cows legs up.

Comment: no it's not. A nontrivial production classpath will tend to have multiple components. As to the multiple satisfiers, that was the whole point of my question. (It's not pathological, it's simply a source directory and the compiled jars, when working remotely between a local dev machine and a test machine. No cow legs present.)

Comment: Again: if you have multiple, *different* versions of a single class on your classpath, something is wrong. No project should rely on classpath ordering to correctly satisfy dependencies. You should never deploy multiple versions of the same library without shading them and rewriting the jars that depend on them.

Comment: Again, the multiplicity was not intentional, but the *question was how to detect the multiple version, not whether that was a good classpath*. I used a standard classpath from someone else, who developed directly on the test machine, and thus had not noticed that the earlier source directory would eclipse later compiled jars. Obviously I fixed the classpath as soon as I discovered this.

Comment: @smci Multiple satisfiers *is* pathological, by definition--and you received several answers, so not sure what your point is anymore. My issue was with "wildcards considered harmful", which I disagree with. Carry on.

Comment: I myself said in the 2nd paragraph of the question and repeated several times, the classpath was not **intentionally** defined to have multiple satisfiers. That's pretty clear. I'm not the guy who defined it, I'm just the guy who had to debug it. The question here was how to find the multiplicity. If we want to open a question on whether wildcards on (long) classpaths are considered harmful and if so why, we can debate that there. Let's stop here.

Comment: @smci I stopped two days ago.

Comment: in this case both the .class and the .jar were on the classpath, in different places. On the local machine, this was bad but unnoticeable. On the remote machine, this gave multiple satisfiers. It's a more subtle form of bad than having the same .class or .jar file in two places